# Asp.net authentication: strange beahviour using different browsers

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i'm using asp.net / windows integrated authentication to 'redirect' my users (intra company) to different page. 
In the web config i have

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

In the Load event of the main page i've this code:

```
      Dim User As System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
      Dim username As String

      User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
      username = User.Identity.Name 'Here i'm getting something like MyDomain\MyName
      If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
          'goto main page
      else
          'goto another page (where to login)
          'and print a label like "Welcome " + username + " to my webpage"
      end if
```

The problem is that i get different beavhiours with different users and browsers.
For instance

- Internet Explorer 8,9 works well: it don't ask me the username
- Chrome works also well
- Firefox: firefox ask me the username and password ( so i enter something like MyCompanyDomain\MyName and my password)

Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling this gave:
[firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication](http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/)

You have to modify a setting in firefox to trust the site for this to work